# Is it possible to prove that any probabilistic metric of 2 distributions will be reduced after any process?

Tags: probability

Let me explain my question more precisely.

Given 2 distributions $P$ and $Q$, and they are defined on the same sample space. Firstly, we use some processing operation $f$ to $x$, where $x$ denotes the sample from the sample space.

And we define a new sample space, after applying $f$ to the old sample space. That is $f(x)=z$, where $z$ is the sample from the new sample space. Then, we can have new distributions on the new sample space: $P'$ and $Q'$.

Is it possible for us to prove this:
$$
D[P||Q] \geq D[P'||Q']
$$
, where $D$ is any probabilistic metric (we can ignore if this metric is a distance), for instance KL divergence.

Moreover, is this related to information process inequality?

thx

Comment: How does $x$ have two distributions?

Comment: What, precisely, is a "probabilistic distance" here?  The KL divergence is _not_ a distance in the usual sense: it is not symmetric and does not obey the triangle inquality.

Comment: Sorry, guys, Let me edit the question again.